# How does getting lost work in Barbarian Prince?

Tags: solo, barbarian-prince

I am trying to get into [DwarfStar Games -- Barbarian Prince](https://dwarfstar.brainiac.com/ds_barbarianprince.html), and am trying to understand the movement rules from the [Rule book](https://dwarfstar.brainiac.com/barbarianprince/barbarianprince_rules.pdf)

For my daily action (r203) I can move to another hex (r204).

**r204** states

> Getting Lost (see r205): each time you try to leave a hex, you may get lost. 
>       See r205 for details. If you get lost, you are unable to get out of the hex
>       by the chosen route, and are stuck for the rest of the day in the hex where
>       you started.  You cannot select an alternate action.

**r205** states (emphasis added):

> Each time you attempt to leave a hex (travel to a new hex) there is a danger of becoming lost.  Consult the Travel Table (r207) and find the terrain type you are leaving.
>       Read across to the "Lost" column entry. Roll two dice. If the dice total equals or exceeds the number there, your party is lost.
>
> If you get lost, you cannot further that day. You are stuck in the hex you tried to leave.   You must check for a travel event **(see r205b)** in the hex you tried to enter, as if you actually entered it.

My confusion is:

Should the "(see r205b)" at the end of that last quote instead read "(see r20**4**b)"?

- Should I perform the Lost AND the Event, or
- Should I perform the Lost OR the Event?

Example from the [Travel Sheet](https://dwarfstar.brainiac.com/barbarianprince/barbarianprince_travel.pdf)

If I am leaving the CountrySide and I roll a 9+ I perform the Lost action (by not moving), **and** I perform the Event Action. Example: if I roll a 1 I follow rule r232 and then end the day.

The reason I am confused is I did not see this correction in the [Errata](https://www.scribd.com/document/26939916/Barbarian-Prince-Official-Errata)

Comment: Would it be worth adding the 'solo' tag to the question?  It may get you more answerers.

Comment: I did it was taken off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that r204b is the Travel Event paragraph, and r205b is the Self-Guiding Moves paragraph, it's pretty safe to call this a typo in the rules. I could see it not being documented in the "official errata", if "official errata" means a correction that was made to the original publication of these rules in the 80s.

The rules language of "you must" is better interpreted as AND than OR. You make a check to avoid becoming lost, AND if it fails, you remain in your current hex and check for a travel event in your intended destination.

Comment: Haven't played this game, but from reading the rules listed in the question it sounds like you do a travel event for the hex you tried to enter, not your current; even though you are remaining in your current due to getting lost.

Comment: Whoops! Yeah, got a wire crossed there. Will edit.